# WatiN won't work with MSpec - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, watin, testdriven.net, mspec

I'm trying to get WatiN working with MSpec in VS2010, using TestDriven.Net.  My code is as follows:

```
[Subject("Whatever")]
public class when_on_home_page {

    private static IE browser;

    Establish context = () =>
        browser = new IE();

    Because of = () => {
        browser.GoTo("http://localhost:1234/");
        browser.WaitForComplete();
    };

    It should_show_add_details_link = () =>
        browser.Link(Find.ByValue("Add Details")).Exists.ShouldBeTrue();
}
```

When I run this, the browser loads the page, but when it checks for the link, I get:

> Whatever, when on home page
>   » should show add details link (FAIL)
>
> Test 'should show add details link' failed:
>     System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>     at mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection.tags(Object tagName)
>     at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEElementCollection.GetElementsByTag(String tagName)
>     at WatiN.Core.NativeElementFinder.FindElementsByTag(String tagName)
>     at WatiN.Core.NativeElementFinder.d__2.MoveNext()
>     at WatiN.Core.ElementFinder.FindFirst()
>     at WatiN.Core.Element.FindNativeElementInternal()
>     at WatiN.Core.Element.get_Exists()
>     NavigationSpecs.cs(20,0): at RoboWeb.Specs.when_on_home_page.<.ctor>b__2()
>     at Machine.Specifications.Model.Specification.InvokeSpecificationField()
>     at Machine.Specifications.Model.Specification.Verify()

Having looked around, I checked the following:

- VS is running as administrator
- TestDriven.Net runs everything in STA mode, apparently
- IE has 'protected mode' turned off
- I can't add the site to trusted sites, presumably because it's running locally
- I call WaitForComplete(), and have also tried Thread.Sleep()

I also tried it with FireFox, but that just crashes.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

[These specifications](https://github.com/agross/mspec-samples/blob/master/WebSpecs/LoginApp.Watin.Specs/LoginSpecs.cs) work for me. Actually, I this is my first WatiN spec; I wrote while trying to reproduce the error you received. :-)

The only special thing I had to do was to turn off IE's Protected Mode. I ran the specs

- on the command line (see `WebSpecs-Watin.cmd` in the repo, please compile the specs project and run the web application from VS before running the cmd)
- with the TD.Net runner
- with ReSharper

They succeed in all three cases. I'm not running as Administrator.

Can you please try to reproduce the error with the project linked above? If you don't have Git installed, there's a download button in the top section.

Comment: Command line works, but Td.Net doesn't - can't find the elements in the page, strangely.  I tried the command line runner on mine and it works, so I guess it's my Td.Net runner which has the problem.  I have the latest version, and I tried running the 'InstallTDNetRunner' batch file in packages\\(mspec)\tools, but no joy.  At least I know where the problem is now, so I can investigate further.  Thanks

Comment: If you're on TD.Net >= 2.24 you don't need to install the TD.Net runner. Just make sure that MSpec.tdnet, MSpec.TDNetRunner.dll and MSpec.dll files are in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, I realised that - I'm on v3, but it didn't make a difference either way.  Everything is in the right folder (mine is installed from NuGet, and yours was right), but I still get the same results.  It does run the MSpec tests, it's the WatiN side which seems to have the issue.  I'll just run it from the command line for now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

System.UnauthorizedAccessException can happen in a number of circumstances. If the page has not loaded fully and you try to access an object, as well as simply not being the right user. I would start by debugging through the script manually, and running the test runner as an administrator.

If that works, then try the combinations of admin & full speed, non-admin and full full speed as well as admin and debugging. Then you should have a good idea as to what the real problem. In some rare circumstances (with early early versions of WatiN,) I had to wrap calls in a try - catch then handle this exception, and then re-try after a short wait.

Comment: Thanks, but no joy: Debugging gives the same error, on this line in IEElementCollection.cs in Watin.Core.dll: '(IHTMLElementCollection)elementCollection.tags(tagName)'.  Catching, waiting, retrying gives the same result.